# C# error when referencing a static method from another class

Tags: c#, class, oop, .net-core

The error involves two files: `GameLogic.cs` and `GameData.cs`, which are in the namespace `AdventureGame` and contain the classes `Logic` and `Data` respectively.

In the `Logic` class, there is a function called `Init()` that contains the following code:

```
public static void Init() // Start the game part of the application
{
    Console.WriteLine(Data.GetLocalisedString("intro_text", "en-gb")); // This line causes an error: "GameLogic.cs(22,22): Error CS0103: The name 'Data' does not exist in the current context"

    for(;;) // Infinite loop
    {
        MainLoop();
    }
}
```

This is the `Data` class which supposedly does not exist

```
public class Data
{
    public static string GetLocalisedString(string stringName, string locale) // Retrieve a string from 
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Strings/lang_" + locale, typeof(Data).Assembly);

        return rm.GetString(stringName);
    }
}
```

I did try qualifying `Data.GetLocalisedString()` with a namespace name as such:
`Console.WriteLine(AdventureGame.Data.GetLocalisedString("intro_text", "en-gb"));`

but this just changes the error to `GameLogic.cs(22,22): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'AdventureGame' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

To reproduce:

In one file, add the following:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Class2.Method2());
        }
    }
}
```

And in a new file, add this:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public static string Method2()
        {
            return "You called method 2";
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, add a main file with this content:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1.Method1();
        }
    }
}
```

Compile the .NET Core project in Visual Studio for Mac (or Visual Studio 2022 if necessary) with .NET 7.0 and the latest C# version, then you should experience the same error I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [supplied repro](https://github.com/nulcow/TextHorrorAdventureCS) the `TextHorrorAdventure.csproj` file contains these three lines of code:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="GameData.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This explicitly tells the build system to ignore the `GameData.cs` file when compiling the code.

Delete these three lines. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Please don't encourage poor questions like this one, that aren't self-contained, by posting answers to them.